# Lambda function error while using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that works in Python 2.7 but not in Python3.7. Here I am trying to sort by values of a lambda function.

```
def get_nearest_available_slot(self):
    """Method to find nearest availability slot in parking
    """
    available_slots = filter(lambda x: x.availability, self.slots.values())
    if not available_slots:
        return None
    return sorted(available_slots, key=lambda x: x.slotNum)[0]
```

The error I get is:

```
File "/home/xyz/Desktop/parking-lot/parking-lot-1.4.2/parking_lot/bin/source/parking.py", line 45, in get_nearest_available_slot
    return sorted(available_slots, key=lambda x: x.slotNum)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add more details perhaps, for how does `x.availability` , `self.slots` etc look like

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple: it's because of how `filter` works.

In Python 2, `filter` is *eagerly evaluated*, which means that once you call it, it returns a `list`:

```
filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [1, 2, 3])
```

Output:

```
[2]
```

Conversely, in Python 3, `filter` is *lazily evaluated*; it produces an object you can iterate over once, or an *iterator*:

```
<filter at 0x110848f98>
```

In Python 2, the line `if not available_slots` stops execution if the result of `filter` is empty, since an empty `list` evaluates to `False`.

However, in Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator, *which always evaluates to `True`*, since you cannot tell if an iterator has been exhausted without trying to get the next element, and an iterator has no length. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more information.

Because of this, a case exists where an empty iterator gets passed to `sorted`, producing another empty `list`. You cannot access the element at position `0` of an empty `list`, so you get an `IndexError`.

To fix this, I suggest evaluating the condition strictly. You could do something like this, replacing `sorted` with `min`, since we only need one value:

```
def get_nearest_available_slot(self):
    """Method to find nearest availability slot in parking
    """
    available_slots = [slot for slot in self.slots.values() if slot.availability]
    if available_slots:
        return min(available_slots, key=lambda x: x.slotNum)

    else:
        return None
```

Comment: nice clear explanation- an alternative would be removing the `if` clause and `next(iter(sorted(available_slots, key=lambda x: x.slotNum)), None)`